# Error while trying to shift row entries of POSIXct time format in R?

Tags: r

I have a data set of time (PSIXct format ) with 'newtime' & 'endtime'

```
datatest <-     
  newtime           endtime
7/7/2017 2:12:00    7/7/2017 2:13:00
7/7/2017 2:59:00    7/7/2017 2:59:00
7/7/2017 18:23:00   7/7/2017 18:23:00
7/7/2017 18:23:00   7/7/2017 18:23:00
7/7/2017 20:40:00   7/7/2017 22:25:00
7/7/2017 20:40:00   7/7/2017 22:33:00
7/7/2017 21:59:00   7/7/2017 22:00:00
7/7/2017 22:35:00   7/7/2017 22:39:00
```

Now I need to shift 'end time' down by one row, so that I can compute difference between newtime and endtime

EXPECTED OUTPUT BELOW

```
datatest1 <-    
 newtime             endtime                 timeDifference (newtimeendtime)
7/7/2017 2:12:00           NA
7/7/2017 2:59:00    7/7/2017 2:13:00              To Be calculated
7/7/2017 18:23:00   7/7/2017 2:59:00             To Be calculated
7/7/2017 18:23:00   7/7/2017 18:23:00             To Be calculated
7/7/2017 20:40:00   7/7/2017 18:23:00             To Be calculated
7/7/2017 20:40:00   7/7/2017 22:25:00             To Be calculated
7/7/2017 21:59:00   7/7/2017 22:33:00             To Be calculated
7/7/2017 22:35:00   7/7/2017 22:00:00             To Be calculated
```

The str output is as below

```
str(datatest) <- 
    $ newtime   : POSIXct, format: "2017-07-07 02:12:00" "2017-07-07 02:59:00" "2017-07-07 18:23:00" ...
     $ endtime   : POSIXct, format: "2017-07-07 02:13:24" "2017-07-07 02:59:28" "2017-07-07 18:23:06"
```

Now am trying to shift 'endtime' by one of the solutions for my earlier query and store it a new data frame 'datatest1' along with 'newtime',

```
 newtime <- c(datatest$newtime)
testtime <- c(datatest$endtime)
time_shift2 <- c(NA,time[1:length(testtime)-1])
time_shift2 <- strptime(time_shift2, format='%H:%M:%S')
datatest1 <- data.frame(newtime,time_shift2)
```

And am getting the following error once I execute the last command from the sequence above

```
Error in data.frame(newtime, time_shift2) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 15005, 12
```

I can also observe on my R console that when i execute the below , from the earlier mentioned sequence

```
time_shift2 <- strptime(time_shift2, format='%H:%M:%S')
```

its showing NA values

```
POSIXlt[1:12], format : NA NA NA NA..
```

Is there any better way to get the expected output , help needed please. Is there any problem with POSIXct format?

TIA

Comment: Use `[-1, ]`, not `[1:length(testtime)-1]`

Comment: Print out every statement and see what's happening. Confer `x <- 1:5;1:length(5)-1;1:(length(x)-1)`.

Comment: @HongOoi <time_shift2 <- c(NA,time[1:length(testtime)-1,])> gives following error  "Error in lapply(X = x, FUN = "[", ..., drop = drop) : 
  argument is missing, with no default"

Comment: How about using data.table and its `shift` function: http://brooksandrew.github.io/simpleblog/articles/advanced-data-table/#using-shift-for-to-leadlag-vectors-and-lists ?

Answer (score 0):

Generate test data:

```
datatest1 <- data.frame(newtime = Sys.time() + 1:10, endtime = Sys.time() + 20:29)
```

Do the shift:

```
datatest1$endtime <- c(.POSIXct(NA), head(datatest1$endtime, -1))
```

Is that what you are looking for?